# How to maintain objects between app sessions?

Tags: ios, serialization, nsuserdefaults

I am currently using singleton instances to access and maintain various `NSObject` in the app.
For instance, I have :

- VariableStores, that maintain several objects such as currentUser (custom `NSObject`), lastLocation (`CLLocation`), etc.
- TaskManager, containing a `NSMutableArray` of `NSOperations` that have failed in order to be re-executed later (such as Instagram with failed upload).

If I kill the app, singleton instances are destroyed and :
 - some data must be retrieved from the server side (for instance, the currentUser) which increase the length duration
 - some data cant be retrieved from the server-side, such as the `NSOperation` in the TaskManager (as they are only managed locally)

Thus, I would like to go further and maintain that kind of objects even if the app is totally killed.

What should I consider as a good practice? Serializing object into `NSUserDefaults` and deserialize ? Is there other best practices?

In case of serializion, serializing objects in `-applicationWillTerminate` delegate and deserializing them in appropriate -init methods of singleton (that are instantiated in the `appDidFinishLaunching`) can be considered as acceptable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the idea of singleton pattern is just to transfer data between controllers without worrying about details ..

what you need to do is a persisting data of your App ..

you can use core data if you see that the data that you need to store is a little big for plists.. or you can use sqlite but that will give you a little pain for writing a lot of sql statements..

or you can use regular plist or nsUserDefaults (i don't like that option) but it's a little slow if the data is too much .. 
you can save this data when app go to background or terminated..

Comment: Hi Mohamed,

NSUserDefaults is quite slow but as it is only at the launch of the app, I think it can be tolerated.

I have been with NSUserDefault finally and serialization to encode Custom objects and it looks like it works fine for the moment.

Thanks for the feedback :)

Comment: great  feel free to promote my answer if you felt that it helped you :)